# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Qt - Drawing Distance Line

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-qt

I'm just starting with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Qt and having gone through many of the examples, I'm looking for advice as to how I would draw a line representing the distance between two points.

My understand thus far is that I can do this in either a graphical layer or in a graphics overlay but which is the preferred option?

I have managed to capture the start and end coordinate in WGS-84 but in terms of doing the actual drawing, I'm a little lost at present

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, given the information you provided you could create a `PolylineBuilder` in WGS-84 SR, add the start and end coordinates, create a line symbol/graphic, and add it to a Graphic Overlay.

```
// create line geometry
PolygonBuilder polylineBuilder(SpatialReference::wgs84());
// build the polyline
polylineBuilder.addPoint(<start x>, <start y>);
polylineBuilder.addPoint(<end x>, <end y>);
// create a line symbol
SimpleLineSymbol* sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbolStyle::Solid, QColor("blue"), 5, this);
// create a line graphic
Graphic* lineGraphic = new Graphic(polylineBuilder.toGeometry(), this);

// create a graphic overlay to display the line graphic
GraphicsOverlay* lineGraphicOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay(this);
// set the renderer of the graphic overlay to be the line symbol
lineGraphicOverlay->setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(sls, this));
// add the graphic to the overlay
lineGraphicOverlay->graphics()->append(lineGraphic);
// add the overlay to the mapview
m_mapView->graphicsOverlays()->append(lineGraphicOverlay);
```

An example of this can be found as a [sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-qt/tree/master/ArcGISRuntimeSDKQt_CppSamples/DisplayInformation/GORenderers)

Comment: Thank you for your response - this is excellent. Presumably, because this "distance line" is frequently re-drawn, it should be kept on an overlay of its own and not intermingled with other graphics on the overlay?